# Plotly: Show value in hoverlabel instead of percentage in stacked area chart `groupnorm='percent'`

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

In the image below, the hoverlabel shows the percent proportionate values. I would rather it show the actual value of each continent on that particular date. I am not sure how to make it happen. For clarity,

Asia would be `9` instead of `37.5`, North America `13` instead of `54.16667` and Europe `2` instead of `8.333333` (according to data provided below)

[image]

| date | value | continent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 3 | Asia |
| 2021-01-02 | 7 | Asia |
| 2021-01-03 | 9 | Asia |
| 2021-01-04 | 13 | Asia |
| 2021-01-01 | 5 | North America |
| 2021-01-02 | 8 | North America |
| 2021-01-03 | 13 | North America |
| 2021-01-04 | 19 | North America |
| 2021-01-01 | 0 | Europe |
| 2021-01-02 | 0 | Europe |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | Europe |
| 2021-01-04 | 3 | Europe |

I tried taking the values directly from the dataframe but hovertemplate does not seem to read any calculations inside the `%{calc}`, it only accepts direct variables. Any help would be appreciated. Use this code to reproduce the graph-

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')) *3,
                   'value': [3,7,9,13,5,8,13,19,0,0,2,3],
                   'continent':['Asia'] * 4 + ['North America'] * 4 + ['Europe'] * 4})

fig = px.area(df, x='date', y='value', color='continent', groupnorm='percent')
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{y}')
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Goal

Keep plot as it is after setting `groupnorm='percent'`, but only display *individual* values in hoverinfo.

#### Answer

1. Include a duplicate column in your `df` for `value` with `df['actual] = df['value']`
2. Include `hover_data = ['value', 'actual']` in `px.area()`
3. Change `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{y}')` to `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata}')`

#### Plot 1

[image]

#### Details

The reason why you'll have to include a duplicate column is that `px.area()` automatically calculates percentages for the column assigned to `y` in `px.area(df, x='date', y='value'...`. When setting `hover_data = ['value', 'actual']`, no calculations are done for `actual` which is later accesible in the hoverinfor through `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata}')`.

If you drop `fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = ...)` from your setup, you'll get the following hoverinfo which may also be of interest:

#### Plot 2

[image]

In this case it might make more sense to change `value` to `percent`, which after all is displayed:

#### Plot 3

[image]

#### Complete code for Plot 1

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')) *3,
                   'value': [3,7,9,13,5,8,13,19,0,0,2,3],
                   'continent':['Asia'] * 4 + ['North America'] * 4 + ['Europe'] * 4})

df['actual'] = df['value']

fig = px.area(df, x='date', y='value', color='continent', groupnorm='percent',
              hover_data = ['value', 'actual'])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata}')


fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for Plot 2

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')) *3,
                   'value': [3,7,9,13,5,8,13,19,0,0,2,3],
                   'continent':['Asia'] * 4 + ['North America'] * 4 + ['Europe'] * 4})

df['actual'] = df['value']

fig = px.area(df, x='date', y='value', color='continent', groupnorm='percent',
              hover_data = ['value', 'actual'])
# fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata}')
  
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for Plot 3

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': list(pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', periods=4, freq='D')) *3,
                   'percent': [3,7,9,13,5,8,13,19,0,0,2,3],
                   'continent':['Asia'] * 4 + ['North America'] * 4 + ['Europe'] * 4})

df['actual'] = df['percent']

fig = px.area(df, x='date', y='percent', color='continent', groupnorm='percent',
              hover_data = ['percent', 'actual'])
# fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata}')
    
fig.update_layout(hovermode='x unified')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Is not it same as not having groupnorm parameter in px.area?

Comment: @Pygirl Haha, yes it is! Oh well, back to the drawing board =)

Comment: @Pygirl I hope you'll find my latest edit to be of better use.

Comment: I was trying to solve it via `customdata` but could not (not knowing how to apply). +1 for demonstration :D. I see so the key point is `hover_data` which I could not find it anywhere on the net.

Comment: @vestland Such a simple solution, thank you! And to think I completely missed `customdata` despite reading the docs page

Comment: @vestland Anyway to also add a separator for the `customdata` in the hoverlabels?

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant Do you mean another separator than `:` ?

Comment: @vestland I mean one for the digits when the digits get too long. They need a comma. My hoverlabel only has figures, eg- `3400000` instead of `Asia: 3400000`. I need `3,400,000`

Comment: @callmeanythingyouwant I would have to look into it. If it's urgent to you, I would consider writing that up as a new question. It's very likely that someone else in here is better at string formatting than I am.

Comment: @vestland Not urgent at all. I'll try and figure it out as well, i'll post a question if i don't get it.